# MDI Parent Child

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have created one MDI form & Want to inherit a already made Child form. So what I have to do to access all controls on my MDI in that child form. (I dont want to create a new inherited form, I have already one)

Comment: You want to access what and from where?

Comment: I have a MDI form & 1 Normal form . now i want to make that Normal form as a child \ inherited form of that MDI. So when i select menu from MDI, that normal form will open

Comment: you can inherit child form from the parent and configure who is mdi parent and who is mdi child when you create them

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear but it appears that you are asking how to show a form as an MDI child. I assume that you have already set `IsMdiContainer` to `true` for your main form.

In order to show an MDI child you need to set the `MdiParent` property for the child form. Like this:

```
ChildForm myChild = new ChildForm();
myChild.MdiParent = this;//this is the main form, the MDI parent
myChild.Show();
```